# How to list the word with the highest ratio, based on their length and score

Tags: c++

I currently have code that prints out the word with the highest score from my dictionary. But I'm looking to expand this so it prints out the word with the highest ratio to word length. Thus i guess this can be calculated via score/word length.

Comment: what do you mean by 'the word with the highest ratio to word length' ?

Comment: Ok well lets say the word plane it has a score of 7.. it's ratio is 1.4 7/5.. and the word red also has a score of 7 but it ratio is 2.3.. Hence words with less letters have a higher ratio...

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question, you don't need two (or three) loops. In the first loop, you already have access to both the word and its score. Keep track of not only `maxscore`, but also `maxword`. In fact, you seem to already have a variable `string word` that can be used for this.

So, after that first iteration, you found the word with the maximum score, and can then print the three pieces of information that you want :

- the word itself (which you stored in `maxword`)
- the score (which you stored in `maxscore`)
- the ratio (which can be easily calculated from the word's length and the score)

If you want to print this information for the word with the highest ratio, it's a simple matter of adjusting the selection criteria (now `score > maxscore`) inside the loop, keep track of `maxratio` and the rest of the code is very similar.

Comment: Ok ill try some things, my main goal is to get the word from my dictionary that has the highest ratio.

Comment: So for `maxratio` would this work.. `int maxratio = score/word.size();`

Comment: @jameskerr : try taking it step by step, following the suggestions in the order that I explained above. And only continue if the code is working : 1) get rid of the second loop by keeping track of the word with the maximum score, 2) print the 3 pieces of information, 3) adjust the selection criterium inside the loop to find the word with the maximum ratio rather than the maximum score.

Comment: Hmm, Im unsure how to keep track of the word with the maximum score.

Comment: @jameskerr : the same way you keep track of the maximum score - by saving it into a variable.

Comment: @jameskerr : this is going a bit beyond the question-answer model of SO ... you should probably refer to a C++ course or textbook to learn about the fundamentals, or find a private tutor to help you out.